# Bought a new headset. Headphones work, mic does not

Tags: microphone, headset

My steelseries siberia v2 headset arrived today. I plugged the headphones and mic into my ASUS VH236H monitor which is connected to my PC via HDMI. The headphones receive sound just fine, but the mic does not work. I know it isn't a hardware problem on behalf of the headset because it's brand new and nothing has changed in my audio control panel. Here's a screenshot of my audio control panel currently:

[image: List of audio devices]

On page 15 (of the pdf, not the manual itself) of the manual to my monitor you can see the ports it has: http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1015465059.pdf

My headphones are plugged into 6 and my mic is plugged into 5.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte X58A-UD3R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's rule out the headset.  Plug the headset directly into the motherboard.

Personally, I don't think that the monitor works in the way you are expecting it to.  I'm not sure, but I don't know if HDMI is enough of an audio-out for the monitor to send it back to the PC, or if the PC knows what to do with the audio it's sending back, as video cards tend to be output only.

Comment: The reason I'm attempting to do it this way is because my PC is far-ish away on the right side of my desk and the cord comes out of the left side of the headphones. If it isn't long enough, I could have no slack to maneuver and the cord might be lying on my lap 24/7 which is extremely irritating. It's a 9.8 foot cord from what I remember so that's what I'm going to try now.

Comment: @ItakeDrukqs Understandable, my desktop is in the same situation.  I'm just going through standard support steps.

Comment: You were right about me thinking that the monitor works that way. I thought it was odd that the port was colored green instead of red for the mic. I'll just have to make some adjustments to my setup to accommodate all of this. The mic works now and sounds wonderful. Thanks a bunch for the quick and efficient assistance.

Comment: No worries, glad it's sorted. :)

If it works like my monitor, it has built-in speakers.  What the line-in does is allows you to hook up an external device (phone, mp3 player, etc) and play audio through those speakers.

Comment: To receive the audio mic signal through a video card, the video card would need to have additional audio-in functionality along the lines of an S/PDIF cable attached to your motherboard from your video card.